# Using Coldfusion to create a REST request

Tags: rest, coldfusion

Using Coldfusion I would like to create a REST service

I would like to post it to: https://www.test.co.za/ using the username "person1" and password "password1".

The data type would be: application/json

And I would like to pass the following parameters:

- callbackURL (string)
- amount (bigdecimal)
- reference (string)
- description (string)

This will then return:

- reference (string)
- redirectURL (string)
- status (string)

This is what I have got so far:

index.cfm

```
<cfset restInitApplication("C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\restApp","IIT")>

<cfhttp url="http://127.0.0.1:8500/rest/IIT/rest" method="get">

<cfoutput>#cfhttp.filecontent#</cfoutput>
```

rest.cfc

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="restService">   
    <cffunction name="sayHello" access="remote" returntype="String" httpmethod="GET"> 
        <cfset callbackURL = "https://www.google.com"> 
        <cfset amount = "100,50">
        <cfset reference = "123456789">
        <cfset description = "This is a description">
        <cfreturn rest> 
    </cffunction> 
</cfcomponent>
```

I would like to know if I am on the right track and how I would post my values to https://www.test.co.za/ with a username and password

I am not sure if it will look something like this:

```
<cfhttp 
    url="https://www.test.co.za/"
    method="post"
    port="8500"
    result="res"> 
</cfhttp>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show some code? Also [check this documentation](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/RESTful+Web+Services+in+ColdFusion).

Comment: @TusharBhaware Thanks! Looks a lot more helpful than what I saw, I will give it a try using that

Comment: Very surprised you didn't think to google "coldfusion rest", the first result for which are the docs.

Comment: I did google that, however it was not very helpful and I still do not understand, I also checked your blog and Ben Nadel's

Comment: OK, you need to be more focused with your questions: *try* something, get stuck, document how you're stuck and what you tried, then raise a question *about that one thing*. Not just "how do I do [this entire concept]". That's just comes across as being lazy (you may have researched it up the wazoo, but unless you detail that, we won't know). Recommend you read this: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html, AND the docs it links to.

Comment: Thanks @Adam I also found this [blog](http://milanchandnacf.blogspot.com/2012/03/rest-coldfusion10-part3.html) that seems to be pretty helpful, I am trying to work through the tutorial now to get a better understanding

Comment: Cool. If you get stuck... *do* raise a question.

Comment: No, I have only "proof of concept" knowledge of CF's REST implementation.